# Can we build a firewall using Raspberry Pi for Whitelisting websites

Tags: firewall, raspberry-pi, whitelist

I intend to build a firewall which allows only specified websites / URLs through it, a feature I could not find in low-cost normally available modems. Can this be achieved through Raspberry Pi?

Secondly, can we allow only specified Android / iOS apps to access network resources through such "firewall"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My $20 home router/modem has this feature and from my experience, it's a pretty common one.

Comment: @gronostaj Could you please tell name and model number of the modem? I'll see if it is available in my country.

Comment: It's TP-Link TL-WR841N, but AFAIR most TP-Link models have it.